# Graph Explorer ErrorInvalidIdMalformed

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using

```
https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/graph-explorer/
```

to test out some things.  When I use

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages
```

I get what I expect,  a list of my folders and messages in my Inbox.  When change me to my email address I get the same information.  Now when I try using a different mailbox I have access to and try to get the messages in "Interesting Messages" I get the ErrorInvalidIdMalformed.  I assume the issue is the space in the path

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/otheremail@company.com/mailFolders/Interesting Messages/messages
{
"error": {
    "code": "ErrorInvalidIdMalformed",
    "message": "Id is malformed.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "f47d4c3b-5681-4b83-b8f4-c2b9be591ff6",
        "date": "2019-02-07T22:39:31"
    }
}
```

I've tried using %20 instead of the space and I still get the error.  Is there a way of having spaces in the URL or do I need to get the mailbox renamed?

TIA,
Joe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the docs for get messages
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0

```
GET /users/otheremail@company.com/mailFolders/{id}/messages
```

You have to use the {id} of the mailFolder. That's why you are getting "ErrorInvalidIdMalformed" as its expecting an id.

You can get this by calling

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/mailFolders
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Wow! A 120 character string if it isn't inbox, clutter, or one of the predefined mailboxes.  Thanks Jeremy it works, but the pain.